# Flutter - Add multistyle text to PDF

Tags: flutter, pdf

I'm trying to add a multistyle text just like in a `RichText` when editing an existing PDF document. Unfortunately, I found two separated PDF plugins that none of them offer me a fully working solution for my need.

Using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) one, I can convert an actual `RichText` to make it appears like one on a page when generating a document.

And [this](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf) one allows me to edit an existing PDF.

I need both features, but I got no idea how to fuse them both to do it.

This one is from [`pdf`](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf).

```
pw.Document().addPage(
 pw.Page(
  build : (pdfw.Context context){
   pw.RichText(text : pw.TextSpan(children : [
    pw.TextSpan(
     text : 'Name :',
     style : pw.TextStyle(pw.FontWeight.bold)
    ),
    pw.TextSpan(
     text : 'Elongated Musk'
    )
   ]));
   return pw.Column(children : children);
  },
 )
);
```

And this part is from [`syncfusion_flutter_pdf`](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdf).

```
String ori = '${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/original.pdf';
sf.PdfDocument doc = sf.PdfDocument(inputBytes : File(ori).readAsBytesSync());
sf.PdfGraphics graph = doc.pages[0].graphics;
graph.drawString('<b>Name :</b> Elongated Musk', ...); //Not really working
```